# Are there methods to determine the stability of functional differential equations?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

For nonlinear differential equations there are methods to determine the stability of fixed points and limit cycles using a phase plane analysis. If I have a functional differential equation with two (or more) solutions how would I determine the stability of the solution functions? Is it correct to think of the solutions like I would think of fixed points of a differential equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do this, but you have to think carefully about the space of functions that you are working with, and what the topology on that space is. It is often possible to solve certain PDE by considering their solutions to be fixed points of a continuous map on a convex subset of a Banach space, such as a Sobolev space. Existence would follow from an appropriate [fixed point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_fixed-point_theorem).

In a similar fashion, you can formulate (theoretically, at least), the concept of stability with respect to the topology you've given on your function space (e.g. induced by the Sobolev norm if you're working with $H^1(\Omega)$, etc). Now, whether you can analyze or determine whether or not you have stability is less obvious to me, and it seems like it would depend a lot on the function you're using.